# How to add a variable condition after catch exception in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Ok, so I have to capture int numbers ranging between 1-24, anything higher than that (24hr format) should display the standard messagebox.show error message. I have tried declaring as follows:

Dim intNumber As Integer
if intNumber >24
show.MessageBox ("24 hour format only")`

it's not working. I am not sure if the previous condition is having an impact on my declaration. Here is my code. Your help is appreciated.

```
'This textbox requests input from user in form of numbers representing Hours of Operation Used and validates data'
Private Sub HoursOfOperation_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HoursOfOperation.TextChanged
    Try
        Convert.ToDouble(HoursOfOperation.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please only type numbers!”)
        HoursOfOperation.ClearUndo()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the actual `Try Catch` but rather should use `Double.TryParse` instead. As for the problem you can't just put your condition with the message in it's `Then` block ?

Comment: After re-reading the question, why do you even choose a textbox for that, there are control more suitable for this (mainly NumericUpDown but even a combobox with a fixed set of values)